# How to set depth limit in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using this spider to crawl a page and download its images:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from imgur.items import ImgurItem
import re

from urlparse import urljoin

class ImgurSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imgur'
    allowed_domains = ['some.page']

    start_urls = [u'some.page']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.*']), 'parse_imgur')]

    def parse_imgur(self, response):
        image = ImgurItem()
        image['title'] = 'a' 

        relative_urls = re.findall('= "([^"]+.jpg)',response.body)
        image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, url) for url in relative_urls]


        return image
```

But I have two issues here, the first one is that I can't set the depth limit to one altought I'm using the "-s DEPTH_LIMIT=1" when I run the spider:

scrapy crawl imgur -s DEPTH_LIMIT=1

The second issue is that I'm getting all the images of the webpage except for the main page:

I'm not getting any images from that page.

Edit.

A@Javitronxo

Like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    image = ImgurItem()
    image['title'] = 'a' 

    relative_urls = re.findall('= "([^"]+.jpg)',response.body)
    image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, url) for url in relative_urls]


    return image
```

I don't get any images that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this rule in your code:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.*']), 'parse_imgur')]
```

The spider is extracting all links from the web page and therefore they will be eventually followed.

If you only want to crawl the images in the main page, I would recommend to remove the rule and change the method header overriding the default `parse`:

```
def parse(self, response):
```

This way the spider will start crawling the images in the `start_url` field, return the object, and finish the execution.

Comment: What can should I put in the parse method?

Comment: Just change the header, the response from the argument will be the start url so you can create the item directly, look for the images in the body, and return it.